# Use Processing's Visual Output In a Custom Container

Tags: java, swing, awt, processing

I was wondering if it were possible to embed a Processing application (i.e. PApplet) inside another Swing/AWT UI, rather than using Processing's default window system. And if so, how would this affect input capture/threading?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible. PApplet extends Applet, which is just an AWT component. You can put an AWT component inside a Swing or AWT window.

Here is a basic tutorial on using Processing from eclipse: https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Once you have that working, you can treat your Processing PApplet class just like any other AWT component.